# Tamil dynasties in Ithihasa

Tags: mahabharata, smriti, tamil

### In Mahabharata

[Mahabharata 8.12](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m08/m08012.htm)

> When that host was being thus struck and slain by heroic warriors the
>   Parthas, headed by Vrikodara, advanced against us. They consisted of
>   Dhrishtadyumna and Shikhandi and the five sons of Draupadi and the
>   Prabhadrakas, and Satyaki and Chekitana with the Dravida forces, and
>   **the Pandyas, the Cholas, and the Keralas**, surrounded by a mighty
>   array, all possessed of broad chests, long arms, tall statures, and
>   large eyes.

[Mahabharatha 3:88](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03088.htm)

> And, O Yudhishthira, in the country of **the Pandyas** are the tirthas
>   named Agastya and Varuna! And, O bull among men, there, amongst the
>   Pandavas, is the tirtha called the Kumaris.

[Mahabharata 5.19](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m05/m05019.htm)

> And similarly, **Pandya, who dwelt on the coast-land near the sea**, came
>   accompanied by troops of various kinds to Yudhishthira, the king of
>   kings.

[Mahabharata 7.23](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m07/m07023.htm)

> Steeds that were all of the hue of the Atrusa flower bore a hundred
>   and forty thousand principle car-warriors that followed that
>   **Sarangadhwaja, the king of the Pandyas**.

If they are mentioned, which means Tamil dynasties existed at that time. However [here](https://controversialhistory.blogspot.in/2007/10/origin-of-cholas-tamil-myth.html) the author claimed that Cholas didn't exist before some century and has given proof. If they didn't exist, could these verses be an interpolation?